# Change the background of selected grouped radio button

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button group and I need to change the background colour on the button which is selected.

The radio button value is returned by a MySQLi query, if the value is "0" change background colour of the selected button to "red", and change the other button to "grey".

I have checked to make sure that the query returns the data I expect, and it does. When I load the form, the wrong radio button (button 1) is always displays as checked.

I have a CSS class for each state:

```js
var mb = result[15];
if (mb == 1) {
  // BUTTON 1 IF QUERY RETURNS "1"
  console.log("MAIN BOARD DISPLAY", mb);
  $('#EditDisplayMainBoard_1').prop('checked', true);

  if ($('#EditDisplayMainBoard_1').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_1")
      .parent()
      .removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label')
      .addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
  }
} else {
  // BUTTON 2 IF QUERY RETURNS "0"
  console.log("MAIN BOARD DISPLAY", mb);
  $('#EditDisplayMainBoard_0').prop('checked', true);

  if ($('#EditDisplayMainBoard_0').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_0")
      .parent()
      .removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label')
      .addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
  }
}
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0.5px solid #CCC !important;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.btn-primary-conf {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #990000;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0.5px solid #CCC !important;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BUTTON 1 GREEN BACKGROUND IF CHECKED -->
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label active">
  Display On
  <span class="rhidden">
      <input type="radio" name="BoardLevel" value="1" id="EditDisplayMainBoard_1">
    </span>
</label>
<!-- BUTTON 2 RED BACKGROUND IF CHECKED -->
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">
  Display Off
  <span class="rhidden">
    <input type="radio" name="BoardLevel" value="0" id="EditDisplayMainBoard_0" >
  </span>
</label>
```

My new code is below but this still does not change the class of each radio group button.

```
if (mb == 1) {
  $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_1")
    .removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label')
    .addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
  $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_0")
    .removeClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label')
    .addClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label');
} else {
  $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_1")
    .removeClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label')
    .addClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label');
  $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_0")
    .removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label')
    .addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: All I can see is changing the EditDisplayMainBoard_1. Where did you want to change the state of EditDisplayMainBoard_0 ?

Comment: @Farhad Mehrad  thanks for looking. I have change the code in the if else statement. My mistake, it should now make sense.

Comment: Should you not be using your server side language to set the active class and checked state when you build the html?  Otherwise where is `results[15]` coming from?  Also, what's the point of the if directly after you check the radio - you've just checked it so you don't need to check if it's checked.  Finally, you just remove and add the same classes, why not just add the active class?

Comment: you don't need .prop('checked', true). remove it in both cases. and just check the if statement. then in .removeClass and .addClass just add or remove btn-primary and btn-primary-con not whole classes. hope it helps.

Comment: @Farhad Mehrad Hi again. I have changed the code and inserted it in the post under New code. But this still does not work and I can't see why, any ideas.

Comment: If it's possible just add or remove btn-primary-conf class not all classes. and put a checkpoint in your html debugger and see if your condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reformatted your post. Now you can clearly see what is going wrong:

Your buttons are like this in HTML:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label active">
  Display On
  <span class="rhidden">
    <input type="radio" name="BoardLevel" value="1" id="EditDisplayMainBoard_1">
  </span>
</label>
```

That's a hierarchy of `label > span > input`.

In your original (first) code, you select the `input` element, then take the parent and remove/add some classes.

However, as you can clearly see from the hierarchy, the parent element is the `span` element, not the `label` element. To reach that, you'll need an additional `.parent()`.

So, assuming the other code is correct, it should be:

```
var mb = result[15];
if (mb == 1) { 
  // BUTTON 1 IF QUERY RETURNS "1"
  console.log("MAIN BOARD DISPLAY", mb);
  $('#EditDisplayMainBoard_1').prop('checked', true);

  if ($('#EditDisplayMainBoard_1').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_1")
      .parent().parent()
      .removeClass('btn-primary')
      .addClass('btn-primary-conf');
  }
} else { 
  // BUTTON 2 IF QUERY RETURNS "0"
  console.log("MAIN BOARD DISPLAY", mb);
  $('#EditDisplayMainBoard_0').prop('checked', true);

  if ($('#EditDisplayMainBoard_0').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditDisplayMainBoard_0")
      .parent().parent()
      .removeClass('btn-primary')
      .addClass('btn-primary-conf');
  }
}
```

Also note that you do not have to remove and re-add the `btn` and `form-check-label` classes, so I have removed those too.

--

A few notes:

1. The way I formatted the HTML (for readability) introduces some whitespace between the `Display On` text and the `span` and `input` elements. This may be visible as spaces on the final webpage. If you don't want that, the easiest solution is to remove the whitespace again.
2. If you want to check which elements are getting their classes changed, you can inspect the elements in the DOM-viewer. Almost every browser has one. Right click the element and select "Inspect Element" or something similar, or press F12 on Firefox or Chrome to open developer tools and go to the 'Inspector' or 'DOM Viewer' tab, then find your elements there and verify that you changed the correct one.
3. Your new code doesn't work for the same reason that the old one didn't: you are not selecting the right element (you need two `.parent()` calls).

Comment: Hi and many thanks for taking the time to look at this issue. Works perfectly, as you pointed out it was the missing .parent().parent(). Again, many thanks.